# whereBetween eloquent query returns empty output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to use 'whereBetween' eloqouent query with two given start and end dates.

```
$first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01 H:s:i'); //get the first day of the current month
$yesterDay = date('Y-m-d H:s:i',strtotime("-1 days")); //get yesterday's date

$d = m_chat_history::where('employee_id',$request->other_id)
                ->whereNull('to_group')->where('to_employee_id',$request->id)
                ->whereBetween('created_at',[$yesterDay,$first_day_this_month])
                ->get();
```

I make sure I have all the required data for the query by 'var_dump' and it did gives me all the required data needed for the query but the query returns me an empty output. Any ideas, clues, suggestions, help, recommendations please? I tried to remove the 'whereBetween' and my query works like it returns me the expected output but with 'whereBetween', the return output is empty.

Comment: The mysql date time format is: date('Y-m-01 H:i:s'); You wrote 'H:s:i' instead of 'H:i:s'

Comment: Don't say "not working", do say "no output". The difference might seem minor but the second phrasing is a sign there's no syntax errors which can be a huge deal.

Comment: @Sovon tried 'H:i:s' but still the same.

Comment: Probably your yesterday date is bigger that first day of month. Smaller one should be at first: `whereBetween('created_at',[$first_day_this_month, $yesterDay])`

Comment: @CodeDemon: are you getting and record if you removed `whereBetween` condition?

Comment: @RaunakGupta: yes im getting a record when 'whereBetween' is removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use the same type and format as `created_at` when defining the values for `whereBetween`. As you're using datetime you could define edge values like (just one of many ways of doing it):

```
$first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01 H:i:s');
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Also make sure of the order of params (still please consider edge cases like first day of the month where $yesterday would be smaller, so you have to add some logic and be careful):

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$first_day_this_month, $yesterday])
```

Edit: wasn't timestamp...

Comment: the 'created_at' column type is 'timestamp'

Comment: Tried your answer but seems not working like still the output is empty.

Comment: Did you change the order of between values as well? This is important.

Comment: Well...are you sure to have data for such period?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I have record in my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121032/discussion-between-dlondero-and-code-demon).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
but first you have to install [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted) with composer.

after doing that

```
use Carbon
```

then write the fallowing code

```
$yesterday = Carbon::yesterday()->toDateTimeString();
$carbon = new Carbon('first day of ' . date('F Y'));
$first_day = $carbon->toDateTimeString();
```

and in your query

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$first_day, $yesterday])
```